# Keyboard shortcut for email address in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to create a keyboard shortcut for my email address in Internet Explorer 11 so that when I fill in forms I don't have to type in a long email address each time.

I have read similar answers for earlier versions of IE and they haven't worked. (with .txt and .bat files)

Could someone help me please?

Comment: AutoHotKey - Free keyboard macro program. Supports hotkeys for keyboard, mouse, and joystick. Can expand abbreviations as you type them (AutoText).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom plugin with Visual Studio.  Here is [video](https://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/video.php?lp=internet-explorer-keyboard-shortcuts) that goes through the process step by step.  You can download Visual Studio Express [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#).

Alternatively, you can create an [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script.  Scripting in AHK is really easy.  The script to enter an email with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> would be:

```
^J::Send, my@email.com
```